# How to UPDATE the data in the database using php

Tags: php, database

im currently creating an `edit.php` page which enables the user to edit the specified data which the user wanted. I followed the tutorial but it doesn't give the results that i wanted to. When I run the `edit.php`, it just display as i wanted but after i clicked `submit` button, there were nothing changed to the data in the database.

This is the code:

```
    <?php
    require('db.php');
    include("auth.php");
    $student_ID=$_REQUEST['student_ID'];
    $query = "SELECT * from student_info where student_ID='$student_ID'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Update Student</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="form">
    <p><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a> 
     | <a href="insert.php">Insert New Record</a> 
     | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
    <h1>Update Student</h1>
    <?php
    $status = "";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']==1)
    {
    $student_ID=$_POST['student_ID'];
    $school_ID =$_POST['school_ID'];
    $student_name =$_POST['student_name'];
    $student_class =$_POST['student_class'];
    mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error());
    $status = "Student Record Updated Successfully. </br></br>
    <a href='view.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
    echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">'.$status.'</p>';
    }else {
    ?>
    <div>
    <form name="form" method="post" action=""> 
    <p><input type="text" name="student_ID" placeholder="Enter Student ID"
    required value=<?php echo $row['student_ID'];?> /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="school_ID" placeholder="Enter School ID" 
    required value="<?php echo $row['school_ID'];?>" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="student_name" placeholder="Enter Student Name" 
    required value="<?php echo $row['student_name'];?>" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="student_class" placeholder="Enter Student     Class"
    required value="<?php echo $row['student_class'];?>" /></p>
    <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If you have any suggestion or any improvement or any link can help me solving this problem, please do so.

This is the original code that the author gave:

```
    <?php
    require('db.php');
    include("auth.php");
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * from new_record where id='".$id."'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Update Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="form">
    <p><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a> 
    | <a href="insert.php">Insert New Record</a> 
    | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
    <h1>Update Record</h1>
    <?php
    $status = "";
    if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)
    {
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $name =$_REQUEST['name'];
    $age =$_REQUEST['age'];
    $submittedby = $_SESSION["username"];
    $update="update new_record set trn_date='".$trn_date."',
    name='".$name."', age='".$age."',
    submittedby='".$submittedby."' where id='".$id."'";
    mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error());
    $status = "Record Updated Successfully. </br></br>
    <a href='view.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
    echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">'.$status.'</p>';
    }else {
    ?>
    <div>
    <form name="form" method="post" action=""> 
    <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" />
    <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" 
    required value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Enter Age" 
    required value="<?php echo $row['age'];?>" /></p>
    <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update" /></p>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Btw, i dont know what this code meant for. I just follow the tutorial.

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']==1)
```

I'm a newbie in this coding world. Thanks

Comment: condition should be `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Submit")`

Comment: i followed your suggestion but it gave me this Notice: Undefined variable: update in `C:\xampp\htdocs\test\edit.php on line 30`

 The is the line 30: `mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no update query in your code :

```
$update = "UPDATE student_info SET school_ID='{$school_ID}', student_name = '{$student_name}', student_class = '{$student_class}'
WHERE student_ID='$student_ID'"; 

mysqli_query($con, $update);
```

Try Something Like This:

```
<?php
require('db.php');
include("auth.php");
$student_ID=$_REQUEST['student_ID'];
$query = "SELECT * from student_info where student_ID='$student_ID'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Update Student</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
<p><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a> 
 | <a href="insert.php">Insert New Record</a> 
 | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
<h1>Update Student</h1>
<?php
$status = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$student_ID=$_POST['student_ID'];
$school_ID =$_POST['school_ID'];
$student_name =$_POST['student_name'];
$student_class =$_POST['student_class'];
$update = "UPDATE student_info SET school_ID='".$school_ID."', student_name = '".$student_name."', student_class = '".$student_class."' WHERE student_ID='".$student_ID."'"; 
mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error());
$status = "Student Record Updated Successfully. </br></br>
<a href='view.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">'.$status.'</p>';
}else {
?>
<div>
<form name="form" method="post" action=""> 
<p><input type="text" name="student_ID" placeholder="Enter Student ID"
required value=<?php echo $row['student_ID'];?> /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="school_ID" placeholder="Enter School ID" 
required value="<?php echo $row['school_ID'];?>" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="student_name" placeholder="Enter Student Name" 
required value="<?php echo $row['student_name'];?>" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="student_class" placeholder="Enter Student     Class"
required value="<?php echo $row['student_class'];?>" /></p>
<p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

isset($_POST['submit']) =>  The isset () function is used to check whether a variable is set or not. The isset() function return true if Submit button has clicked.

Comment: Hey, thanks. It's really helpful and it solved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong in your case

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']==1)
```

It should be

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Submit")
```

Because value of your input with name submit is "Submit"

Comment: i followed your suggestion but it gave me this
 `Notice: Undefined variable: update in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\edit.php on line 30`

The is the line 30: `mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error());`

Comment: You need to write the update mysql query, in the if condition using the new values inputted
This should give you a start with that
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: Because There is No $update variable in your code. Check this code : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42312018/4049692, Here have declared update variable before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

what this means is that    // if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']==1) when that post submit value is passed and the post submit value matches 1 the code below should run. to update database as you said, do this and upvote if it works contact for more

```
        $updatequery = "UPDATE student_info SET student_ID = '$student_ID', school_ID = '$school_ID', student_name= '$student_name', student_class='$student_class'";

        $runthequery($con, $updatequery);
        if($runthequery){
         means if run the run variable is successfull do something
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is like `$_GET`. They get provided to your PHP file when a call is made to the page. You `<form>` action is empty so it is sending the form data to itself. The page loads once with GET when the user sees the form and a second time when the data is POSTed to it.

`if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']==1)`

This line is a conditional that says to only run the code when the form data is received. Right now your code isn't indented so it will be hard for you to read. Make sure you are using a code editor with syntax highlighting and fix your indents. It will make you life easier.

**All that to say ... You have not defined `$update` in your example so you aren't actually executing any SQL.**